# Can't build OS image with Scons. Where i made mistake? [FIXED]

Tags: linux, scons, osdev

i'm trying to studying in OS development but now have some troubles with SConstruct scripting.
First at all, i'm follow the YT tutorial of OS development.

(Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ohT59ZfXo6k&list=PLFjM7v6KGMpiH2G-kT781ByCNC_0pKpPN&index=18&ab_channel=nanobyte)

And now stopped in the middle of Live, where SCons replace make files.

**My tool chain:**  gcc 13.1.0 + binutils 2.39 (during building with .mk i not getting any problems (In-build gcc is 11.4.0 and binutils 2.38))

SConstruct code taken from source tutorial repository:
https://github.com/nanobyte-dev/nanobyte_os/tree/master

All scripts with building are same that I have. But anyway I'm getting an error every time.

Main SConstruct script: https://github.com/nanobyte-dev/nanobyte_os/blob/master/SConstruct

First stage script: https://github.com/nanobyte-dev/nanobyte_os/blob/master/src/bootloader/stage1/SConscript

Second stage script: https://github.com/nanobyte-dev/nanobyte_os/blob/master/src/bootloader/stage2/SConscript

Image creation script: https://github.com/nanobyte-dev/nanobyte_os/blob/master/image/SConscript

I'm getting next **error**.

```
> scons: Reading SConscript files ... scons: done reading SConscript
> files. scons: Building targets ... Assembling
> [src/boot_loader/fst_stg/boot.asm] Linking   
> [build/i686_debug/fst_stg_fat12/fst_stg.bin] i686-elf-gcc: fatal
> error: '-fuse-linker-plugin', but liblto_plugin.so not found
> compilation terminated. scons: ***
> [build/i686_debug/fst_stg_fat12/fst_stg.bin] Error 1 scons: building
> terminated because of errors.
```

My ubuntu distro is Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Also with locate i can see that liblto_plugin.so in my tool chain:

> ```
> .../tool_chain/gcc-build-13.1.0/gcc/liblto_plugin.so
> .../tool_chain/gcc-build-13.1.0/lto-plugin/.libs/liblto_plugin.so
> .../tool_chain/i686-elf/libexec/gcc/i686-elf/13.1.0/liblto_plugin.so
> ```

**UPDATE**

I fix this issue by installing another linux distributive (Was Ubuntu -> Now it is Fedora)

Comment: "have some troubles with SConstruct scripting." - So, do you just build **existing project** or do you **write your own**? In the last case you need to put the code into the question post itself. For debug why some compiler/linker option doesn't work you need firstly to determine the **exact command line** which invokes it. In case of SCons, this can be achieved by setting appropriate `*COMSTR` variable to the empty string.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Yes, I'm writing my own project, but because I only understand this issue, it is almost no different from the code from the repository. But still, here's a link to what I'm writing: https://github.com/j1sk1ss/CordellOS.EXMPL

I will add *COMSTR and update question post in few hours.

Also i think that problem situated in tool chain, and today i will try to recompile project on my macbook.

Comment: Glad you got it fixed, though switching distros isn't a common answer :)   Something like what you hit is "always a path problem" - you know you have the library file, but the link doesn't find it, that would suggest `LIBPATH` isn't set quite right. The SConstruct sets that from `toolchainGccLibs`, which is built up to include a middle `/lib/` but your locate output shows it in a path including `libexec` instead. That was probably your problem. Disabling the override of `LINKCOMSTR`, as suggested by @Tsyvarev would probably have let you see.

Comment: @Mats Wichmann Yes, switching to another OS with a complete reinstallation is not the best solution, but anyway I solved the problem and now very happy!
In addition, changing the distribution was not difficult for me, since Ubuntu was not my main system...